# New year resets recent reputation activity on username hover?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, activity-dropdown

When I hover over my username at the top of the page, I usually get a short list of my most recent reputation activity.

It appears that only activity that occurs this year is showing up, however.  Activity that occurred yesterday does not appear in this feed, though it does appear in the reputation activity section of the userpage.

Since this is not reset on a new week, or new month, it doesn't make sense that it's reset on the new year.

Answer (score 5):

The profile dropdown shows what happened this week, month, and year...these are all the same thing and all reset when the year changes, it's behaving as it should.

The profile reputation summary has no defined time range, it's not showing the same breakdown or range it's just showing the "most recent positive changes," also as it should - they're not *supposed* to show the same thing.  Note the profile version is more expensive and cached for a longer duration - there are performance considerations in play as well (for now).

I think we've clearly labeled the dropdown on the top bar's time ranges, tagging this [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Comment: This year, the first day is Sunday. Does the reset for the week counters happen even if the first day of the year is Wednesday?

Comment: @kiamlaluno - nope, the days the resets happen are still respected...so the week won't match up next year, it'll always reset on Sunday.